# Как решить проблему с ботом ВК? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Есть бот в ВК, который парсит данные с сайта и отправляет их человеку.

Вот пример кода:

```
def main():
    file = open('token.ini', 'r')
    token = file.read()
    token = str(token.strip())
    file.close()
    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=token, api_version=5.103)
    longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)
    vk = vk_session.get_api()
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me and event.text:
            if event.from_user:
                if event.text.lower() == 'начать':
                    vk.messages.send(
                        user_id=event.user_id,
                        message='Приветствую тебя, друг! Перед тобой появились кнопки для управления ботом воспользуйся ими!',
                        random_id=0,
                        keyboard=keyboard
                        )
                elif event.text.lower() == 'в меню':
                    vk.messages.send(
                        user_id=event.user_id,
                        message='Вы попали в меню!',
                        random_id=0,
                        keyboard=keyboard
                        )
                elif event.text.lower() == 'получить данные':
                    event_user_id = event.user_id
                    get_info
                else:
                    vk.messages.send(
                        user_id=event.user_id,
                        message='Я не понял твоей команды. Для начала работы с ботом напишите Начать.',
                        random_id=0
                        )
```

get_info отправляет пользователю картинку, так-же пример кода:

```
vk.messages.send(
            user_id=event_user_id,
            attachment=','.join(attachments),
            random_id=0,
            message=''
        )
```

attachments это список с приложенными картинками формата `[photo{owner_id}_{photo_id},и так далее]`

И если написать боту "получить данные" все вроде в порядке, но после отправки картинки он 4 раза флудит текстом из `else:` в функции `main` как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Получив полный код, разобрался с проблемой. Дабы сохранить в тайне*
>   *назначение решения, опишу логику ошибки, не вдаваясь в подробности*
>   *реализации конкретного примера. Предыдущий мой ответ тоже актуален, но*
>   *описывает ошибку иного рода, которая тоже может критично повлиять на*
>   *работу бота, так что создал второй ответ.*

В реализации функции `get_info` присутствует чтение сообщений от пользователя и их обработка. Посредством клавиатуры и просто сообщений. Клавиатура, собственно, и отправляет сообщение с текстом кнопки.

```py
def get_info(...):
    vk.messages.send(
        user_id=event_user_id,
        message='Выберите ...',
        random_id=utils.get_random_id(),
        keyboard=keyboard_name
        )
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        ... #Обработка сообщений от пользователя
```

Сообщения ловятся благодаря методу `VKLongPoll.listen()` из **vk_api**. Работает он следующим образом:

Каждое сообщение пользователя возвращается в виде генератора с помощью ключевого слова **yield**. Когда вы вводите `longpoll.listen()`, у вас создается, грубо говоря, постоянно обновляемый итератор, по которому вы и идете, ловя сообщения:

```py
for event in longpoll.listen()
```

Из github **vk_api**:

```py
 def listen(self):
        while True:
            for event in self.check():
                yield event
```

Так вот:

После того, как функция `get_info()` обрабатывает 4 ваших сообщения, они добавляются не только в итератор **внутри** функции, но и в ваш **родительский итератор** в функции `main()`.

В итоге, итерируя на уровне `main()`, бот читает команды, предназначенные для обработки в функции `get_info`, и конечно же, не понимает их, ведь они описывают **получаемые данные** в `get_info`. Эти команды не выглядят, как что-то из *['Начать', 'в меню', 'получить данные']*, поэтому для каждой из этих команд мы переходим в else и пишем, что команда нам непонятна.

На вашем месте, я бы продумал сначала структуру решения, прежде чем приступать к реализации, чтобы проблем с решением подобных оплошностей потом не возникало. Как человек не знакомый с **vk_api**, могу предложить костыльное решение:

Пусть `get_info()` возвращает как значение с ключевым словом **return** количество сообщений, которое было отправлено пользователем боту от входа в функцию до, собственно, ключевого слова **return**. Внутри `main()` первой же строкой заведите переменную `msgCounter = 0` и используйте эту функцию следующим образом:

```py
msgCounter = get_info()
```

Перед обработкой команд *['Начать', 'в меню', 'получить данные']* напишите:

```py
while msgCounter:
    msgCounter -= 1
    continue
```

Это решит вашу проблему.

Answer (score 2):

Вы вызываете функцию `get_info` по ссылке без скобок в конце, что значит вы выполняете ее как процедуру, не отдавая на вход никаких параметров, и запускаете в **отдельном процессе**. Насколько мне известно, оно не захватывает данные из пространства функции, из которой была вызвана, а также не бросает ошибок, поскольку выполняется в другом процессе параллельно.

Я попытался воссоздать вашу программу и протестировать. С вашей проблемой я не столкнулся, но функция `get_info` очевидно не работала. После того, как я передал функции все необходимые для работы аргументы, она заработала без ошибок. Получив изображения, я мог продолжать дальше пользоваться ботом без каких-либо проблем.

```
def get_info(vk, event_user_id):
    vk.messages.send(
                user_id=event_user_id,
                attachment=','.join("photoSOMEUID_SOMEMID"),
                random_id=0,
                message='test'
            )

...
#in main():
...
 elif event.text.lower() == 'получить данные':
                    event_user_id = event.user_id
                    get_info(vk, event.user_id)
...
```

Comment: Если это не исправит положения:

Если предоставите полную цепь вызовов, которую проходит программа в момент возникновения ошибки, можно будет разобраться детальнее. То есть от момента вызова `get_info` до последнего сообщения хорошо бы было видеть все функции, определенные переменные и вообще всё, чего касается ваша программа.

Сейчас же при наличии этой информации, я думаю, что это максимум, который можно выжать.
Например, мне непонятно откуда вы берете изображения для прикрепления к сообщению.

Comment: Можно где нибудь с вами связаться для того чтобы предоставить код? Например, Дискорд.

Answer (score 1):

Я не уверен в своих словах, но всё же напишу предположения.

1. Используйте метод из vk_api utils.get_random_id или генерируйте random_id, а не используйте 0.
2. Отключите в настройках LongPoll 'Исходящее сообщение'. Настройка -> Работа с API -> LongPoll API -> Типы событий.

Comment: Не помогло, всё еще флудит после выполнения функции.