# event.text принимает значение message или как ждать сообщение от пользователя

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, бот

> Почему-то в функции func значение event.text принимается, в качестве message, который был написан до этого. Как это исправить или как заставить бота ждать новое сообщение от пользователя.

```
def func(user_id):
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW :
            if event.user_id==user_id:
                if event.from_user:
                    x=event.text
                    return (x)
def menu ():
    vk.messages.send(
        user_id=event.user_id,
        random_id=get_random_id(),
        message='Еще раз, добро пожаловать в наш сервис !\n1 - отписаться\подписаться на рассылку\n2 - Информация о нашем сервисе\n3 - Управлять уведомлениями о зарядке')
user_id=event.user_id
    x=func(user_id)
```

Comment: Не надо `for event in longpoll.listen():` в функции звать несколько раз, это же ужасно. Слушайте сообщения, не выходя из этого цикла.

Comment: А как слушать ?

Comment: Не выходя из цикла. Начинайте цикл в main

Comment: Я пробовал, но ничего. Если не сложно, можете показать пример, как это может выглядеть

Comment: [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1118278/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%92%D0%9A-python) тоже бота делал автор вопроса. У него структура поудобнее будет.

Comment: кстати, там у автора проблема была связана с подходом к чтению сообщений, похожим на ваш. Прочитайте ответ и возьмите на заметку

Comment: Проблема, как мне кажется, не в чтении сообщений, ибо я пытался проверить проходит ли пользователь или нет в основной цикл и заметил, что это не происходит